# value of variable {5} is not set

Tags: java, spring-mvc, properties

This is in my properties file:

```
message=You are scheduled {0} at {1} {2} for your {3} at {4}. We'll see you then! Any questions please call {5}.
```

Java code for setting values:

```
String[] msgParams = new String[6];
msgParams[0] = "Tire Rotation"
msgParams[1] = "2016-06-03"
msgParams[2] = "12:00"
msgParams[3] = "vehicle"
msgParams[4] = "dehli"
msgParams[5] = "9876543210"

String message = messageSource.getMessage("message", msgParams , Locale.getDefault());

System.out.println(message);
```

Output is:

> You are scheduled for a Tire Rotation at 2016-06-03 12:00 for your vehicle at dehli. Well see you then! Any questions please call {5}.

Value of `{5}` is not set.

Comment: Is it 12:00 or 00:00?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is there a space in front of the phone number, and could you also show the message from which you start (so containing the place holders)

Comment: Just remove `'` from your message **We'll**.

Comment: @jankigadhiya i don't want to remove ' it. do you have any other solution

Comment: see my answer @Rohit

Comment: Interesting how your config doesn't match your output ... When you create an example, then, please, take more care.

Comment: @Tom everyone can easily understand what is my problem. so if you have answer than please give me. Don't give such advice

Comment: I shouldn't give the advice, that you write proper questions? Then don't be mad if someone downvotes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find it. Use **''** instead of single **'**

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe because you are missing this `\`before `'` :

message=You are scheduled {0} at {1} {2} for your {3} at {4}. We\'ll see you then! Any questions please call {5}.

Comment: If i used \ than result will You are scheduled for a Tire Rotation at 2016-06-03 12:00 for your vehicle at dehli. Well see you then! Any questions please call {5}. but if i remove ' than it is working fine. but i can't change message. plz help how can i set {5} with '